# Laravel 5 модификация/апгрейд/изменение данных из модели на вывод

Tags: laravel, orm, eloquent, модель-данных

Для получения юзера в контроллере:

```
User::find($id)
```

Но мне необходимо модифицировать данные юзера, полученные из таблицы, допустим прописать путь аватарки (не для того чтоб сохранять обратно, а просто на вывод)

```
$user->bigAv=...
```

В своем фреймворке я делал все просто - получал из таблицы, и оберткой модифицировал как хотел, в итоге удобно одним методом получал обработанного юзера.

В laravel же приходит в ум только каждый раз вызывать по 2 метода, которые и выглядят как-то не совсем логично:

```
$user=User::find($id); 
$user=User::upgradeUser($user);
```

Либо второй вариант - дописать метод в модель, и вызывать так:

```
$user=User::find($id)->upgradeUser();
```

Но тут во-первых почему-то не передается массив $this->data в метод upgradeUser (в отличие от примера выше), в котором находится путь к той аватарке. Во-вторых, все равно смотрится избыточно, т.к. добавляется второй метод.

Как правильно получать в контроллер модифицированные данные полученные из таблицы по модели?

Comment: Да, хочу сразу одним методом обработанные данные. У меня в коде юзер - ходовой объект, уже 3 раза применился и везде с этим дубляжом. А если посчитать сколько еще надо будет применить + такая же ситуация будет для другой модели? Хочется сразу знать как правильно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) В моделе:

```
protected $appends = ['bigAv']; 

getBigAvAttribute(){
   return public_path($this->avatar)
}
```

2) Для таких вещей как доп полня или какая-то обработка над моделью используйте библиотеку [fractal](http://fractal.thephpleague.com/), есть даже пакет для [Laravel/fractal](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-fractal)

Comment: Спасибо первый вариант то что нужно. Но вот как в него массив $this->data из контроллера передать? При способе `User::upgradeUser($user);` - передает автоматически , а тут нет его.

Comment: не понял зачем так мудрить ? у вас же пользователь выбран, что вам нужно в нем изменять сделайте метод public тогда любой который нужен, зачем передавать в пользователя самого пользователя ? $this используйте

Comment: допустим для примера - мы получаем баланс юзера. И хотим вывести этот параметр с добавкой "рублей", либо "р." - в зависимости от того, что находится во внешнем массиве `$this->data`  . Но как нам получить этот внешний массив?

Comment: Это не должно реализовываться в моделе, используйте фрактал

Comment: Благодарствую:)